# How does a chroot system interact with the kernel

Tags: kernel, chroot

I am trying to debug an [OpenGL issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227126/hardward-opengl-rendering-in-matlab) in a piece of closed source software. The software supposedly works in Debian Wheezy and I would like to get it working in Arch. I tried running it in a Debian Wheezy chroot from my updated Arch system and I get the same issue. Assuming the software actually works in Wheezy, is it possible that there something about the old Wheezy kernel (with whatever Debian patches) that would allow OpenGL to work better than in the newer (essentially unpatched) Arch kernel?